# How to restrict white space as first character and allow space after character in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular

I have tried to restrict special characters and white space as first character but i am able to achieve in restricting special characters but i am not able to restrict space as first character. I have used custom pipe. Also attached working demo.
So now, special characters has been restricted in the input field, so i have to restrict space as first character and allow space after alphanumeric.

**HTML:**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control min-w300" placeholder="Search Agent" [(ngModel)]="wildCardSearch" (ngModelChange)="searchChange($event)" appInputRestriction>
```

**Ts:**
I have taken selector as `appInputRestrictor` and i have used it like this.

```
 regexStr = '^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$';
  @Input() isAlphaNumeric: boolean;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }


  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event']) onKeyPress(event) {
    return new RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key);
  }

  validateFields(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {

      this.el.nativeElement.value = this.el.nativeElement.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, '').replace(/\s/g, '');
      event.preventDefault();

    }, 100)
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnd5kj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Please add the relevant code here to create a [mcve]. If the external link is deleted or modified, the question will have no future value

Comment: @adiga, i have pasted code as well, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is called **this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart**

This is the code base for you.

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) { 

   if ( this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart === 0 && event.key === ' ' ) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }

    if (!RegExp(this.regexStr).test(event.key)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

I also have created Demo for this. Please check this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iws9ns

Comment: Hi @Aakash, in the above answer is it possible to allow - so that i can search phone number with 623-4567-987